# How to get access and initialize variables t1-t6(TextView)

Tags: java, android, initialization, fragment

Need to get access and initialize variables t1-t6(which are in Fragment) from my activity. There is a big trouble for me, if you have any ideas please tell me).If you need more details - no problem)

Code:

PageFragment.java

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "arg_page_number";
    TextView t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6;
    int pageNumber;
    String a;



    static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);

        pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return pageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

    }





    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);
        String a = getArguments().getString(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);
        t1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t1);
        t2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t2);
        t3=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t3);
        t4=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t4);
        t5=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t5);
        t6=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t6);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to access them? Why not create a method in your fragment class to change them and call from your parent activity?

Comment: Are you saying the variables t1-t6 are in the class `Fragment`? They're also in your example class here `PageFragment`. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

you mean that the t1-t6 are in the activity and you want to use them in fragment 
so you need to just

```js
TextView t1=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.t1Id);
```

and do it for the others

Comment: Need to initialize variables which are in fragment.xml from My activity.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i understood your question right but it seems like you want to initialize t1-t6 which you will work on them from fragment but the initialization is in activity well if so

in your fragment do this for all of textviews

```js
        static TextView t1;

        public static void setT1(TextView t1) {
            YourFragment.t1 = t1;
        }
```

and in your activity do the below

```js
TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
YourFragment.setT1(t1);
```

and do it for the others but i don't know why do you want to use it this way